# How to init a materialize textarea with character count without using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, materialize

I can't use HTML only to show the Character Counter from MaterializeCSS. The website example is implemented in jQuery. I can't use jQuery in my React project so I wonder if there's a way to init a MaterializeCSS textarea with character count just by using materializeCSS's JS? There is a workable date-picker in materializeCSS's JS below as a example, Thanks a lot!

[Character Counter from MaterializeCSS website](http://materializecss.com/text-inputs.html)

```js
< script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js" > < /script> <
script >
  const datePicker = document.querySelector('.datepicker');
const datePickerInstance = M.Datepicker.init(datePicker);

//TODO:How to modify these two statements below to make textarea character counter workable by using materializecss' js, just like the "date-pick" one above? Cause materializecss says it doesn't require jQuery as a dependency.

const textNeedCount = document.querySelector('textarea #description');
const textNeedCountInstance = M.CharacterCounter(textNeedCount);

<
/script>
```

```css
<!-- CSS --><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"><!-- Compiled and minified CSS --><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <title>Parallax Template - Materialize</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
  </header>

  <main>
    <div class="row">
      <br>
      <form class="col s12 m6">
        <!--description-->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <textarea id="description" class="materialize-textarea" data-length="50"></textarea>
            <label for="description">描述</label>
          </div>
          <div class="input-field col s12 colorDataPicker">
            <i class="material-icons prefix">textsms</i>
            <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="date-pick">
            <label for="date-pick">生日</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>

    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't ask so specific, I wonder if there is a statement like this:var elem = document.querySelector('.carousel');
  var instance = M.Carousel.init(elem, options);
  which could be achieved by using materializecss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const textNeedCountInstance = M.CharacterCounter(textNeedCount);
```

The error you are getting is `TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function`. This means that this is a class and it needs to be instantiated with the keyword `new`.

```
const textNeedCountInstance = new M.CharacterCounter(textNeedCount);
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/wwukaaab/

Comment: Thank you Ivan, but I just couldn't make it workable using your code... Can you help me rewrite the two statement above in JS part? I comment by //TODO.  (And I just remove the Vanilla Js part cause I leave it by accident after accepted someone's modify)

Comment: @TingWiggin I answered your new question.

Comment: @TingWiggin Please accept the answer to close the question.

Comment: Wow!!! It works! You saved my day Ivan~ Thanks a loooot ！(I had arranged these code words in all different ways like do the Permutations... Just never open the console)

Comment: The static init method should be used. `M.CharacterCounter.init(document.querySelectorAll('.has-character-counter'));`

Answer (score 1):

Per https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/5730

You should initialize character counters like this:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.has-character-counter');
M.CharacterCounter.init(elems);
```

Comment: Don't forget:
``` import M from 'materialize-css'; ```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
/**
 * Materialize Character Counter Initialization
 * 
 * Initialize the Character Counter for the element
 * textarea <textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
 * 
 * @{issue} https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/5730#issuecomment-377773535
 * 
 * @doc https://materializecss.com/text-inputs.html#character-counter
 * 
 * @returns Character Counter instance
 * 
 */
const initCharacterCounter = () => {

    return document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

        const elem = document.getElementById('textarea')
        return  M.CharacterCounter.init(elem)

    })

}

initCharacterCounter()
```

Comment: Can you provide a short description on how your code differs from the original poster's question, or note that your code is the same and works?

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import M from 'materialize-css';

useEffect(()=>{
  const elems = document.querySelectorAll('.counter');
  M.CharacterCounter.init(elems);
}, [])

// or, using class components:
componentDidMount() {
  const elems = document.querySelectorAll(".counter");
  M.CharacterCounter.init(elems);
}
```